# ParseResults as a parameter of getCommandManager().execute

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge, minecraft-fabric

I'm encountering a problem which I have not found anywhere else online as everyone is using

```
CommandManager().executeCommand(player, string); //string is the command
```

which for some reason is not recognized, perhaps it's defunct. What is recognized, however is

```
CommandManager().execute(ParseResults, string) //string is the command
```

I am not sure what ParseResults is, but what am I supposed to put in there if I'm not parsing anything? Errors are thrown in the case of inputting a world, server, player or command.